# SQL check constraint breaks further transactions on EF Core DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a check constraint on a table, which checks that the value supplied for the `[NormalisedName]` is the uppercase version of the `[Name]` during an insert/update.

```
([NormalisedName]) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS = (upper([Name])) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

The constraint works fine in manual SQL statements, no matter how many times I get one right or wrong, every time I use the following query I get the expected result that passes or fails depending on my "varying_validity":

```
insert into [Roles] ([Name], [NormalisedName]) values ('<name>','<varying_validity>')
```

Consecutive statements like this also work as they should (two entries, 1 and 3):

```
insert into [Roles] ([Name], [NormalisedName]) values ('iwork','IWORK')
insert into [Roles] ([Name], [NormalisedName]) values ('inotwork','IasfasfWORK')
insert into [Roles] ([Name], [NormalisedName]) values ('ishouldwork','ISHOULDWORK')
```

---

Now I've went on to using entities in EF CORE .NET 6.0.15 to add to these tables:

```
    string name1 = "1 works ok";
   
    var role1 = new Role() { Name = name1, NormalisedName = name1.ToUpper() };

    try
    {
        _context.Roles.Add(role1);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
```

This also works fine!

And when I try consecutive adds:

```
    string name1 = "1 works ok";      
    string name3 = "3 should also work here";

    var role1 = new Role() { Name = name1, NormalisedName = name1.ToUpper() };        
    var role3 = new Role() { Name = name3, NormalisedName = name3.ToUpper() };

    try
    {
        _context.Roles.Add(role1);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        _context.Roles.Add(role3);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

Again, works fine.

But if I get an error on one of these inserts, the following ones that are *correct* also fail with the same error, as if the check has failed and now the table just can't get over it.

```
    string name1 = "1 works ok";
    string name2 = "2 should fail";
    string name3 = "3 should work but does not";

    var role1 = new Role() { Name = name1, NormalisedName = name1.ToUpper() };
    var role2 = new Role() { Name = name2, NormalisedName = name2 };
    var role3 = new Role() { Name = name3, NormalisedName = name3.ToUpper() };

    try
    {
        _context.Roles.Add(role1);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        _context.Roles.Add(role2);
        _context.SaveChanges(); // Fails here, jump to exception, ignore, carry on with role3
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }

    try
    {
        _context.Roles.Add(role3);
        _context.SaveChanges(); // ALSO FAILS!!
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

Why does the `role3` insert fail now, just because `role2` failed? DO I need to be "resetting" the constraint / table / dbcontext state somehow?

I get the feeling it's somehow hanging on to the identity of the row that was attempted.

Comment: Check to see if issue is in the Server or the Entity.  I would connect to  the SQL Server Management Studio and with explorer check the log files under management.  The server should give a much better error message.

Comment: `role2` is still attached to DBContext so if you try to make another `SaveChanges()` after you add it, it will fail again, you need to detach it in order to have a successful `SaveChanges()` afterward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `role3` failed to save because `role2` is still attached to the context. In this case you should change the state for entity with `role2` when fails.

```
 ctx.Entry(ent).State = EntityState.Detached;
```